# Identify all interfaces of computer by giving host

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming, dns

doing little network projects for identification interfaces of computer.

Id like to just use Ping, DNS, TCP to achieve it.

Eg. I give google.pl as hostname, I obtain ip.

```
string host = "google.pl";
IPAddress[] address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);
```

Ok iv got IP. Now how can I check witch interface it use to communicate?

Comment: Connect with TCP, fails? Connect with UDP, fails? .. etc. :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, then it's impossible. There are thousands of different protocols the computer could be using to communicate, many of them proprietary. And even if you somehow managed to detect all of the protocols used today, new ones are going to come into existence.

Answer (score 0):

This by no means is an easy problem to solve reliably, so outsource the functionality to another program.

The easiest way to accomplish this is to write an adaptor to use the NMAP shell program, and then parse out the output.